# Duplicate rows where a column contains ","

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, unnest

I have data as below

```
name    subject
a       m1
b       m2
c       m1, m3
d       m4, m5, m6
e       m7
```

I would like to duplicate entire row where column `subject` contains `,` . The original data has many more columns than shown here. I will duplicate a row equal to number of `,` in the `subject` column, so I will repeat `c` 1 times and `d` 2 times

I don't know how many cells in the `subject` column would have `,` and there is no upper limit to number of values in a cell of the `subject` column

Then I would like to keep only one value on the duplicated rows such that all values from the subject column appear once

```
name    subject
a       m1
b       m2
c       m1
c       m3
d       m4
d       m5
d       m6
e       m7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can use [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select t.name, value as subject
from mytable t
cross apply string_split(subject, ', ')
```

`string_split()` returns a unique column, called `value`.

Comment: could you explain how `cross apply` works? How would it ensure that we are correctly repeating rest of the columns?

Comment: @user2543622: that's [a lateral join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply). If you want more columns from the original table, just list them in the `select` clause.

Comment: can i say `select t.*, values as subject1` and then remove `subject`?

Comment: @user2543622: in SQL Server you cannot "remove" a column from the resultset. You can do `select t.*, value as subject1`, and you get both `suject` and `subject1` in the resultset. Else, you need to list all column names (expect `subject`) in the `select` clause.